# CSS specificity, parent container overrules sub container

Tags: css, 960.gs, css-specificity

I'm strugling a bit with some custom 960.gs classes that I'm using. Problem occurs when I'm using a sub-container, and the sub-container's column simply inherits the width from the main-container's column rules.

In my opinion the inner cells (foo + bar) should be green. Meaning they should get the rules of `.container-6 .grid-3` instead of `.container-8 .grid-3`

I'm aware of the `!important` option in CSS, but I would like to investigate other options first, because that would be a problem if the situation was the other way around.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-8">
    <div class="grid-3">
        <div class="container-6">
            <div class="grid-3 alpha">foo</div>
            <div class="grid-3 omega">bar</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-5">test
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  min-width: 990px;
}

div {
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.container-6 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    width: 684px;
}
.container-6 .grid-3 {
    width:312px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.container-8 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px;
    border: 1px solid silver;    
}
.container-8 .grid-3 {
    width:340px;
    border: 1px solid blue;    
}
.container-8 .grid-5 {
    width:580px;
    border: 1px solid red;    
}

.alpha {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.omega {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.grid-1,
.grid-2,
.grid-3,
.grid-4,
.grid-5,
.grid-6,
.grid-7,
.grid-8 {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

I have made this fiddle to illustrate my problem. I have taken out the non-related 960.gs rules.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f6Wb4/)

In my opinion the inner cells (foo + bar) should be green. Meaning they should get the rules of `.container-6 .grid-3` instead of `.container-8 .grid-3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a style that's applied in the context of the inner container to always trump when it's nested inside any other container, you could write it like this:

```
 [class*="container-"] .container-6 .grid-3{
     border: 1px solid green;
 }
```

The part in square brackets is an attribute selector. The asterisk indicates a wild-card, so this part matches any element that has the sub-string `container-` anywhere in its class attribute.

So in your case, since  `container-8` satisfies the condition for the first part of the selector, this rule will apply and have a higher specificity. And it will work the same way if you nest your .container-6 inside of *any* 960.gs container, trumping any style rule declared with 2-class specificity.

Caveat: IE-6 and lower doesn't support attribute selectors.

Comment: You sir.. is awesome! I have added this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uNkj3/) which shows how the rules apply both ways, with container-6 nested in container-8 and vice versa. I haven't implemented it into my application yet, but I'm pretty sure it will stick!

Answer (score 1):

Both of these rules have 2 classes, so they are tied when it comes to specificity. In that case, the latest rule in the css file gets applied. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for further explanation.

To change it to green, you could swap `.container-6 .grid-3` and `.container-8 .grid-3` in the CSS file

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f6Wb4/3/)

Comment: You're solution is fit for my specific case, where the case of having container-8 inside container-6 will probably never happen. Thus i have implemented that in my application. Still looking for a more universal solution.

Comment: ok, you would probably have to add some id's if you want to work around this. an id will always trump a class when it comes to css-specificity.